# Show a list of downloads

Tags: swift, mvc, ios

I've been working on a Swift project that involves a seedbox app for my NAS, and I would appreciate some feedback on the code structure and especially on the placement of my observer. I've implemented a `DownloadListViewModel` and a corresponding `DownloadViewController` to display the list. The `DownloadListViewModel` fetches data from an API periodically, and the `DownloadViewController` updates its UI accordingly.

I'm specifically concerned about whether I've placed the observer in the right location within the code. Should it stay in the `DownloadListViewModel` as it is now, or would it be more appropriate to move it into the `DownloadViewController`? Your insights and suggestions on the overall code quality and best practices would be highly valuable.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
    class DownloadListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var downloadList: [Data] = []

    let qnapApi = ApiClientQnap.shared
    var timer: Timer?

    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            print("update!")
            self.fetchDownloads()
        })
    }
    
    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
        
    func fetchDownloads() {
        
        // Appel de l'api qui va remplir notre tableau
        qnapApi.performQuery { queryList in
            if let queryList = queryList {
                // Hop on récupère la liste
                self.downloadList = queryList.data ?? []
            } else {
                print("Erreur lors de la récupération de la liste de téléchargement.")
            }
        }
    } }

struct DownloadViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @State var data: [Data] = []
    var onSelected: ((Data) -> Void)?
    @StateObject var viewModel = DownloadListViewModel()

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> DownloadViewController {
        let tableViewController = DownloadViewController()
        tableViewController.onSelected = { selectedData in
            self.onSelected?(selectedData)
        }
        return tableViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: DownloadViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.updateData(viewModel.downloadList)
    }

    func updateData(_ newData: [Data]) {
        self.data = newData
    } }

class DownloadViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data: [Data] = []
    var onSelected: ((Data) -> Void)?

    private var dataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Data>!

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "DownloadViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DownloadViewCell")
        
        dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, Data>(tableView: tableView) { tableView, indexPath, dataItem in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DownloadViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadViewCell
            cell.myLabel.text = dataItem.source_name
            cell.updateProgressView((dataItem.progress!) / 100)
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DownloadViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadViewCell
    
        cell.myLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].source_name
        cell.updateProgressView(Float(data[indexPath.row].progress!) / 100)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let selectedData = data[indexPath.row]
        onSelected?(selectedData)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    func updateData(_ newData: [Data]) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.data = newData
            var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Data>()
            snapshot.appendSections([0])
            snapshot.appendItems(newData)
            self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
        }
    } }
```